# Regarding Index out of range error

Tags: python, indexing

```
def sum_squares(n):
    sum=0

    for i in range(1,len(n)+1):
        sum=0

        for j in range(1,n[i]):
            sum+=j**2

        print('The sum:',sum)
n=[2]
sum_squares(n)
```

Here, I am getting an error in the line `for j in range(1,n[i]):`
When it is `i-1` it works, but what is needed is `i`.

Comment: If you have `for i in range(1,len(n)+1)` you are having `i` go past the end of `n`, so the subsequent call to `n[i]` will raise an exception.

Comment: Python lists are zero-indexed. For n-element list first element has index 0, and last has index n-1. You are trying to access indices 1, 2, ... n - last index is absent.

Answer (score 0):

When `i=len(n)`, `n[i]` indeed will raise an IndexError. You need to adjust the first range:

```
for i in range(0, len(n)):
```

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0 so you should do:

```
def sum_squares(n):
    sum=0

    for i in range(0,len(n)):
        sum=0

        for j in range(1,n[i]):
            sum+=j**2

        print('The sum:',sum)
n=[2]
sum_squares(n)
```